# Cron job on Ubuntu for php

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I'm using Ubuntu on the server and I'm using Putty to access. I want to create cronjobs for my php site. How can I do this?

Comment: Also please don't ask your question more than once, if you realize you're not explaining yourself correctly, click the edit link on your question and add more information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you mean that you want your php site to do some regular tasks, there are two possible ways.

1) You use cron to pull a certain page regularly. You can do this with a text-based browser, e.g. lynx. You pull your script like this:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/lynx http://yourhost.com/cron.php -dump > /dev/null`

(This will call it every minute. That way you can build your own schedule inside your application)

2) You call your script with the command line php interpreter:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/cron.php  > /dev/null`

Generally solution two is better. However you will need access to the box. The cron in solution one can be triggered from a different host, if you cannot install crons on the host.

Also beware of a common pitfall using the command line version of php. On debian (and potentially other systems) there may be seperate php.ini files for cgi, cli and mod_php. If you have customized your configuration make sure that the command line php is using the correct one. You can test this with:

`/usr/bin/php -i | less`

In response to the comment by dimo i made some benchmarks. I called a simple local php script (which just echos "test") 1000 times with lynx, wget and php-cli:

```
kbsilver:temp kbeyer$ time . wget.sh

 real 0m14.223s
 user 0m2.906s 
 sys 0m6.335s

(Command: wget -O /dev/null "localhost/test.php"; 2> /dev/null) 

kbsilver:temp kbeyer$ time . lynx.sh 

real 0m26.511s 
user 0m5.789s 
sys 0m9.467s 

(Command: lynx -dump "localhost/test.php"; > /dev/null) 




kbsilver:temp kbeyer$ time . php_cli.sh 

real 0m54.617s 
user 0m28.704s 
sys 0m18.403s 

(Command: /opt/local/bin/php /www/htdocs/test.php > /dev/null)
```

Server is `lighttpd`, `php(fastcgi)` with apc (on Mac OS X).

It turns out that indeed wget is the best tool for the job regarding speed.

So the result of `php-cli` is not that suprising as the other methods reuse an already running php thread with opcode cache.

So the only real advantage of using php-cli is security as the script will not be available from outside as you can put it outside the docroot.

(This test is obviously not 100% accurate, but the differences are quite obvious in my opinion)

Comment: I imagine wget is a better tool for this than lynx -dump

Answer (score 1):

I'm asssuming you want to backup your PHP site?  Edit the crontab using:

```
crontab -e
```

This will start up an instance of vi in which you can edit the crontab, press **i** for insert mode.  You then need to put in the information for when the cron entry will run and the command to run at that time, e.g.:

```
30 10 * * * tar -zcvf ./myphpsite.tar.gz /var/www/phpsite
```

So the command above will tar gzip your phpsite in /var/www/phpsite at 10:30pm every day.  Exit and quit vi with **:wq**

See this for further reference:

http://www.adminschoice.com/docs/crontab.htm