# How do I get cron to call update my site (PHP)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I want to update my site every 5/10 minutes using `cron`. I'm connecting to my server (Ubuntu) using PuTTY. I edited the `crontab` file but it doesn't seem to work... What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by refresh?  Update your live site from a development copy?

Comment: You're a little too sparse with your question. How does your crontab look like, what is the script you are calling from cron? Are there any error messages?

Please be a little verbose.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210930/cron-job-on-ubuntu-for-php

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the poster is looking for something like this.

Add a line in your crontab:

```
01,11,21,31,41,51 * * * * root /path/to/php/application /path/to/website/update_script.php
```

That would have every 10 minutes update_script.php would be run