# How to execute a php script every day

Tags: cron, ubuntu-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cron job on Ubuntu for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210930/cron-job-on-ubuntu-for-php)

I am running and ubuntu server and wanted to run a php script every day. I have done some research and found that cron is the best way of doing this however, this is where i got stuck, a lot of the information on the internet about cron is very hard to follow and understand.

So i wanted to execute a simple php script once a day, the script i made for testing simply just deletes a record from a database, but the real script will do a lot more.

I tried setting up a task through plesk which is provided through my web host service but it didn't seem to execute when i wanted it to, i used 1 for minutes, 22 for hours, * for day, * for week and * for month and thought this would execute every day at 22:01.

I have the directories on my server:
cron.hourly
cron.daily
cron.weekly
cron.monthly

I thought i could dump i file in there and it would execute for example every day, but i'm guessing i need to make a cron script to call a php script right?

If i were to go the way of putting a file in the cron.daily folder how would i go about it?

Also if there are any steps i need to take on the php side please let me know?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's couple of ways to setup cron job. Assuming you got shell access you could do `crontab -e` from console and define job there, i.e. like this:

```
1 22 * * * command
```

which would trigger `command` (whatever it is) at 22:01 each day (not sure why you set minutes to `1` instead of `0` though). To launch PHP script from there you would either have to install `php-cli`, and then invoke it that way:

```
1 22 * * * <path>/php -q script.php
```

You can also call bash script here, to setup all the stuff like paths etc and then call your php script form bash - sometimes it is simpler to do that way instead of crafting way too long command line for cron. And it's simpler to update it later. also, you could turn your php script into bash-runnable script by setting it execution bit (`chmod a+x script.php`) and adding shell's shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
   ...
```

If your script got too many dependencies and you'd prefer to call it via web, you could use `wget` to mimic a browser. so your `command` would be:

```
/usr/bin/wget --delete-after --quiet --spider <URL-TO-YOUR-SCRIPT>
```

wget manual can be accessed by `man wget` or `wget -h`, or is [on this website](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). Aternatively you may use `HEAD` tool from `perl-www` package - but it requires perl while wget is a standalone tool. If you use HTTPS with self signed certs, add `--no-check-certificate` to your invocation arguments. And you may also want to setup `.htaccess` and limit web access to your cron script to localhost/127.0.0.1

Comment: Could you explain those attributes a little i'm not sure what -r to --spider does. thanks.

Comment: Most likely `-r` is not required in your case: `"‘-r’ / ‘--recursive’
Turn on recursive retrieving."` - i edit the answer, but `--spider` is useful as you do not really need to download the page output, but just make httpd start it: `"--spider’ When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there."`. Alternatively could use `HEAD` tool from perl www package. `wget -h` or `man wget` will give you detailed information or look here http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html.

Comment: So if use the command crontab -e the 1 22 * * * command /usb/bin/wget --delete-after --quiet --spider http://www.mysite.com/dostuff.php that would run that file every day? and i wouldn't have to change any of the paths or anything for the php inside this file? Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Yes, this (mind the http:// url prefix) `1 22 * * * command /usb/bin/wget --delete-after --quiet --spider http://mysite.com/dostuff.php` would poke http://mysite.com/dostuff.php script via web each day at 22:01. Of course `wget` toolhave to be installed on the serwer, but it shall be not an issue (`sudo apt-get install wget` to ensure)

Comment: Thats amazing, i guess we'll find out tonight at 22:01 if it has worked :P On a side note, is there a way to test it without waiting that amount of time or setting it to run every minute?

Comment: Sure. Just check what time it is now, and set cron job i.e. in next minute :) I.e. its 13:04 now, so set it "5 13" and wait (make sure server clock is running accurate and the same timezone just invoke `date` and see)

Comment: Just to double check, i don't need to restart cron or anything like that?

Comment: The answer to that is no i don't! Thanks a bunch for your help, its been the best help i've had on this website!

Comment: No, cron does not need to be restarted as editing cron jobs via `crontab` is sufficient for daemon to notice the change.

Comment: Please note that the answers alternatively refer to "/usr" and "/usb".  On my Amazon Linux, the correct location is /usr/bin/wget.

Comment: `/usb` things was ordinary typo.

Answer (score 3):

every minute:

```
* * * * * /path/script.php
```

every 24hours (every midnight):

```
0 0 * * * /path/script.php
```

Se this reference for how crontab works: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference, and this handy tool to build cron jobx: http://www.htmlbasix.com/crontab.shtml