# CronJob BackUp: run every day, week, month

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I did some google search for this but all I can find is separate things and the cPanel's interface is a little bit confusing to be honest.
[image]

Basically, I have this script to create files+mysql backup:

```
<?php

$auth = base64_encode(":");
$domain = "";
$theme = "";
$secure = false;
$ftp = false;
$ftpserver = "";
$ftpusername = "";
$ftppassword = "";
$ftpport = "21";
$ftpdirectory = "/";

if ($secure) {
    $url = "ssl://" . $domain;
    $port = 2083;
} else {
    $url = $domain;
    $port = 2082;
}

$socket = fsockopen($url, $port);
if (!$socket) {
    exit("Failed to open socket connection.");
}

if ($ftp) {
    $params = "dest=ftp&server=$ftpserver&user=$ftpusername&pass=$ftppassword&port=$ftpport&rdir=$ftpdirectory&submit=Generate Backup";
} else {
    $params = "submit=Generate Backup";
}

fputs($socket, "POST /frontend/" . $theme . "/backup/dofullbackup.html?" . $params . " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Host: $domain\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Authorization: Basic $auth\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Connection: Close\r\n");
fputs($socket, "\r\n");

while (!feof($socket)) {
    $response = fgets($socket, 4096);
    echo $response;
}

fclose($socket);

?>
```

I would like to run that PHP file so it backups up my stuff exactly like the cPanel would on any regular shared hosting plan: Daily, Weekly and Monthly. I want to do this because of my website got screwed up because the hosting company backup was not working properly.

1. Do I need to create separate cron jobs for daily, weekly, monthly or I can do all of them at once?
2. If I input a command in the <kbd>Command</kbd> field, is it enough to get it working or I need to setup the other input fields?
3. What's the correct command to run my backups as explained above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that interface, you have a few different options for the command,

```
php -q /path/to/your/script.php
```

would work.

If you add `#!/usr/bin/php -q` to the top of your PHP script, then you can just call it directly from `cron`:

```
/path/to/your/script.php
```

The general answers to your questions (not having to do with that web interface) are covered here:

[How to execute a php script every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215524/how-to-execute-a-php-script-every-day)

This might also be helpful, a random but pretty decent reference on crontab syntax:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: So, I need to create a cron job for daily, another cron job for weekly and another for monthly?

Comment: I'd say that the main advantage to separating out tasks in a backup by daily, weekly, monthly, etc. is that you can do different things with the different jobs, and use the different hooks to set your backup retention policy. For example, you might want to keep only last 10 dailys, but have 12 monthlies to cover roughly the last year. Etc. Etc. The poorman's way to do it is to just do it daily and then manually delete old ones before you run out of hard disk space. Also, checkout `rsnapshot`.